# Checking if config value is empty not working

Tags: xml, magento, php

I am trying to check if a config value is empty in my view.phtml file for product page. Here is the code in view.phtml:

```
<?php if (!empty($_config['size_chart_attribute_identifier'])):?>
    <a href="#size_chart" id="size_chart_link" class="fancybox">
        <?php echo $this->__('size chart') ?>
    </a>
    <div style="display:none">
        <div id="size_chart">
            <?php $cmsstatic = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('size_chart')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); 
            echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockID($cmsstatic)->tohtml();?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif;?>
```

My portion of config.xml file looks like:

```
<meigee_blacknwhite_productpage>
            <general>
                <collateral_related>related_slider</collateral_related>
                <relatedposition>bottom</relatedposition>
                <moreviews>moreviews_slider</moreviews>
                <moreviews_hover>0</moreviews_hover>
                <prevnext>prevnext</prevnext>
                <product_sku>1</product_sku>
                <productimg>zoom</productimg>
            </general>
            <layout>
                <collateral>collateral_tabs</collateral>
                <productsidebar>right</productsidebar>
                <pagelayout>productpage_large</pagelayout>
                <collateral_position>underdetails</collateral_position>
            </layout>
            <brand>
                <productbrand>1</productbrand>
                <brandformat>.png</brandformat>
                <brandsearch>1</brandsearch>
                <brandtarget>1</brandtarget>
                <brandpos>sidebar</brandpos>
            </brand>
<size_chart_attribute_identifier></size_chart_attribute_identifier>
            <additional>
                <product_custom>blacknwhite_product_custom</product_custom>
                <product_related_content></product_related_content>
            </additional>
            <rich_snippets>
                <status>1</status>
                <breadcrumbs>1</breadcrumbs>
                <product_ratings>1</product_ratings>
                <product_price>1</product_price>
                <product_availability>1</product_availability>
            </rich_snippets>
        </meigee_blacknwhite_productpage>
```

and system.xml portion looks like:

```
<size_chart_attribute_identifier translate="label">
    <label>Size chart attribute identifier</label>
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>45</sort_order>
    <comment>
    <![CDATA[If you wish to display link to size chart, enter the attribute identifier here. Empty to disable. <a href="https://www.shopshark.net/knowledgebase/article/257/how-to-create-size-charts/" target="_blank">More info</a>.]]>
    </comment>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
 </size_chart_attribute_identifier>
```

In the admin panel I can enter the value I want and save it (it saves properly).

But when loading the product page, nothing is displayed even if there is text saved to the `size_chart_attribute_identifier` in admin.

I also tried just echoing `$_config['size_chart_attribute_identifier']` and got nothing returned. If I take away the if statement the code shows properly. but I need the if statement..

Comment: did you try to construct condition in opposite if(condition): // nothing; else: // do something; endif; ?

Comment: @martin just tried that and yes if I do an opposite if it does show the code, so it definitely is not seeing that the size_chart_attribute_identifier has a value

Comment: I figured it out. I had to point to the theme config file

Comment: @Sackling Please add that as an answer and give a short example what you did to solve it.